# Java - code to convert string to post script file using Ghostscript

Tags: java, ghostscript

I never worked with postscript before... And I need to replace a tool that:

1. **Converts a string to postscript**
2. Generates a pdf file based on a postscript file (done)

My issue is: I have no idea how to achieve step 1. By the way, I would preferably do in a similar way to the one I did on step (2).

I was wondering if I can just replace the parameters, but how? Could you please assist me?

The code to item (2) is below:

```
public byte[] convertPostScriptToPDF() throws IOException {

            //get Ghostscript instance
            Ghostscript gs = Ghostscript.getInstance();

            File file= new File (this.getClass().getResource( "/resources/employer_report_last_page2.ps").getFile());//(Config.EMP_REPORT.REPORT_LAST_PAGE_STORE_PATH);
            File pdfGenerated = File.createTempFile("output", "pdf");
            System.out.println("Path for temp file -> " + pdfGenerated.getAbsolutePath());

            //prepare Ghostscript interpreter parameters
            //refer to Ghostscript documentation for parameter usage
            String[] gsArgs = new String[10];
            gsArgs[0] = "-ps2pdf";
            gsArgs[1] = "-dNOPAUSE";
            gsArgs[2] = "-dBATCH";
            gsArgs[3] = "-dSAFER";
            gsArgs[4] = "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite";
           // gsArgs[5] = "-sOutputFile=output2.pdf";//output file name
            gsArgs[5] = "-sOutputFile=" + pdfGenerated.getAbsolutePath();
           // gsArgs[5] = "-sOutputFile=" + file.getAbsolutePath();
            gsArgs[6] = "-c";
            gsArgs[7] = ".setpdfwrite";
            gsArgs[8] = "-f";
           // gsArgs[9] = "input.ps";//input file name
            gsArgs[9] = file.getAbsolutePath();//input file name

            //execute and exit interpreter
            try {

                gs.initialize(gsArgs);            
                gs.exit();

            } catch (GhostscriptException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdfGenerated);
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);

     }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I hope you are doing good. You have any idea how to pdf into multiple pages. I mean let's i have PDF file with 50 pages. I want to split into 50 pdf files using ghostscript. Let me know for clarification

Answer (score 0):

I got no solution, so I realized I could try a workaround...

I changed the application logic. At the end it would convert everything to pdf, so instead of :

- convert string to ps
- add ps content other ps
- convert ps to string

I did:

- onvertd string to pdf
- convert ps to pdf
- merged both using the PDFMergerUtility